# How to stop allure report publisher in Jenkins from changing my build status to Unstable due to failed tests?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, allure, playwright-test

So I have a jenkins pipeline for a project where the test results do not matter (e2e test suite). I am currently integrating Allure to the Pipeline but it keeps changing the build status to Unstable due to failed builds and even overriding the build status to SUCCESS in the last stage of pipeline has no effect.

I recently read about skipMarkingBuildUnstable:true feature in JUNIT reporter, is there an Allure equivalent to it?

this is how my allure reporter is configured in the pipeline:

```
'Generate Allure report': {h->
        script {
          try{
            allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk              : '',
                    properties       : [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results          : [[path: '/allure-results' ]]
            ])
          } catch (e) {
            echo "Allure report was not generated : ${e}"
          } finally {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          }
        }
     }
```

I've tried setting build result to SUCCESS, inserting the allure report in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a direct equivalent in the [Allure Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin/) to the `skipMarkingBuildUnstable: true` parameter available in the [JUnit reporter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/).

You might try and use a custom wrapper script: You could execute your tests and generate Allure results outside the Jenkins Allure plugin, and then simply archive these results as build artifacts. That way, the Allure results will not have an effect on the build status. You would lose some integration features, but it would work.

```
'Generate Allure report': {h->
    script {
      try {
        // Run your tests and generate Allure results here using shell scripts or other Jenkins steps
        sh 'your_test_command_here'
        sh 'allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report'

        // Then, archive these results
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'allure-report/**', allowEmptyArchive: true
      } catch (e) {
        echo "Allure report was not generated : ${e}"
      } finally {
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      }
    }
 }
```

That will allow you to archive the Allure report without letting it dictate the build status. That approach might lose some of the Jenkins Allure Plugin's features, but would give you the control you need over the build status.